# The term 'tasklist' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Tags: powershell, tasklist

I have run the `tasklist` and `gwmi` in PowerShell and get the following error:

```
tasklist : The term 'tasklist' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+  tasklist
+  ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tasklist:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: What version of Powershell and Windows? Are you running as admin?

Comment: Check if `Test-Path -LiteralPath 'C:\Windows\System32\tasklist.exe'` returns True. Check if `C:\Windows\system32` is included in `$env:Path`. Do you get the same error when you run `tasklist.exe`?

Comment: Thank you Ansigar.....perfect solution  of problem....